# Finding the sum of NUMBERS in a string?

Tags: java, string, methods

I have to find the sum of numbers in a string which contains "a-z", "0-9" and "-", if there is "-" before the number I count this number as negative. 
For example I have this text:

`asd-12sdf45-56asdf100`, the sum of numbers `-12,45,-56 and 100` is `77`.

I managed to replace all the letters and it came out `-12 45-56 100`, and I am stuck here. I tried splitting into array and then `parseInt`, I tried some things with loops, but dead end... Any help?

It might not be entire code; if you give just a hint, I can probably figure the rest out myself.

Here is the code I've wrote so far.

```
String text = "asd-12sdf45-56asdf100";
String numbers = text.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]+", " ");
String[] num = numbers.trim().split("[ ]");

int sum = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < num.length; index++) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(num[index]);
    sum += n;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

P.S: I am still in the beginning of my IT education, so keep it as simple as possible :D Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please make an attempt and after that post your code. Stackoverflow community can't give you ready solution, first you have to try to solve it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry! :)

Comment: Hint: A) dont use user input in such firsts tests, just **hardcode** a string example in your code (that also makes it possible for your readers to understand what that code is doing ... and B) when you already have code that is not working, see [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, made it right.

Comment: I think what you came up with already is not too bad.  The only thing that's still a problem in this approach is the '45-56'.  But that's easily solved by just making sure that any minus sign is always preceded by a space.

Comment: Yes! That was another of my attepts :D So I guess I will try to achieve that now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "-12 45-56 100";
int sum = Stream.of(s.replaceAll("-", " -").split(" ")).filter(e -> !"".equals(e)).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
```

Comment: OP got as far as this: `-12 45-56 100` notice the space is not before the minus sign as of yet. Maybe fix that first and then your answer will be great.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like a homework question for you to learn regular expressions. So I am not going to answer this for you. But you might find a tool like the following useful to play with regular expressions:

- https://regex101.com/
- https://www.regextester.com/
- https://regexr.com/

Also there are tons of resources out there, to read about how to use regular expressions:

- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: I tried using regular expressions but the regular expression is crazy and this task isn't supposed to be that hard. And still it didn't really worked using regular expressions as well :( But these sites are very useful! Thanks!

Comment: It depends. There are often multiple working regular expressions, in this case it can be rather simple. My advice would be to generate multiple test string, one without numbers, one with only single digit positive number, one with multiple digit positive number and then one like the one from your question. Then try to solve them starting with the easiest first. And don't worry about complexity. Regular expressions for the beginner are almost always too much, give yourself some time to understand the concept. It's a really really powerful tool for any developer, so it's worth the struggle.

Answer (score 0):

You can add negative numbers and positive numbers to separate lists and add them separately and then do the subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match the numbers that may be occurring in the string. The regex I am using is based on the assumption numbers can occur with or without a negative sign in the string.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "[-]*[0-9]+";
        final String string = "asd-12sdf45-56asdf100";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        int sum = 0;

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found number: " + matcher.group(0));
            sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0));
        }

        System.out.println("Sum = "+sum);
    }
}

Output : 

Found number: -12
Found number: 45
Found number: -56
Found number: 100
Sum = 77
```